MacOS: How do I give my program permissions during development?
I"m developing an app on macOS.
It's a tauri app which links to a custom library (written in objective-C so I can access some system functionality).
The issue is, some of the functionality in the custom library, requires permissions in order to work.
How do I give my tauri program permissions?
Because this is a dev program and not an installed program, I can't give the program permissions via system Privacy & Security in the System Settings.
I've also tried to give the library permissions via xcode but because this is a library and not a app, I don't have the Signing & Capabilities tab, so I can't give the library permissions through xcode.

You have to add an Entitlements.plist file to your Tauri app and define the path to that file in the tauri.bundle.macOS.entitlements setting. See the macOS Bundle page in the Tauri guide. You will also find a link to the description of the various entitlements there.
The Entitlements.plist file could look like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.print</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>


I don't think the question is asking about entitlements. It's about access permissions, which is a different thing entirely.

From the Tauri page: "Entitlements control what APIs your app will have access to". Yes, they are not the same, but sandboxed apps need to state which capabilities they want to have. The question does not tell which permissions are required, but if the library needs the network, camera, USB or whatever, it is worth a try.
